# Generating the coefficients of a Chebyshev polynomial in Python

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

I am trying to compute the coefficients of the *k<sup>th</sup>* Chebyshev polynomial. Let's just set *k* to 5 for this. So far, I have the following:

```
a = (0,0,0,0,0,1) #selects the 5th Chebyshev polynomial
p = numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev(a) #type here is Chebyshev
cpoly = numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.cheb2poly(p) #trying to convert to Poly
print cpoly.all_coeffs()
```

After the second line runs, I have an object of type `Chebyshev`, as expected. However, the third line fails to convert to a type `Poly`, and converts to type `numpy.ndarray`. Thus, I get an error saying that ndarray has no attribute `all_coeffs`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is 'NP' package ? i guess it stands for umpy... and are you sure cpoly has 'all_coeffs' method ?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? for `cheb2poly`: --> `Convert an array representing the coefficients of a Chebyshev series, ordered from lowest degree to highest, to an array of the coefficients of the equivalent polynomial`

Comment: @Zohar yes, it stands for numpy..should've converted that before posting on here. cpoly does not have that method. But I'm not sure how to define cpoly so that it does.

Comment: @cel If cheb2poly is not the right method to call, do you know which is?

Comment: I think you are simply misusing the method. The docs explicitly state that you should pass coefficients and get coefficients. You actually pass a polynomial object and expect to get a polynomial object, which is simply not what the method does.

Comment: try x=cpoly[0]; x.coef[<coefficient_ix>]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@cel** has the right idea in the comments - you need to pass the *coefficients* of the Chebyshev polynomial to [`cheb2poly`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.chebyshev.cheb2poly.html), not the object itself:

```
import numpy as np

cheb = np.polynomial.chebyshev.Chebyshev((0,0,0,0,0,1))
coef = np.polynomial.chebyshev.cheb2poly(cheb.coef)

print(coef)
# [  0.,   5.,   0., -20.,   0.,  16.]
```

i.e. *16x<sup>5</sup> - 20x<sup>3</sup> + 5x*. You can confirm that these are the correct coefficients [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).

To turn these coefficients into a `Polynomial` object, you just need to pass the array to the `Polynomial` constructor:

```
poly = np.polynomial.Polynomial(coef)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import numpy.polynomial

In [2]: p = numpy.polynomial.Chebyshev.basis(5)

In [3]: p
Out[3]: Chebyshev([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

In [4]: p.convert(kind=numpy.polynomial.Polynomial)
Out[4]: Polynomial([  0.,   5.,   0., -20.,   0.,  16.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```